# jQuery Show items based on form selection and hide the others

Tags: jquery

Hey There,
This is a pretty simple problem, but it is my first time using '.not' and I don't think I am using it correctly.

Basically when I get these  fields to show I want to hide any other that are already visible. So you can only interact with 1 at a time.

If you can please take a look at this and show me where I am going wrong that would be awesome! Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Psvab/6/

Comment: What's with the double-dollar notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hide them all and show the one you want.  Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.coursedate').hide();
    $('#course_type').change(function() {
        var optionValue = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.coursedate').hide();
        $('#'+optionValue).show('fast');
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Psvab/10/

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  When you try to hide all the other options, you aren't selecting the correct elements.  Try this:

```
$('#course_type').change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var selected = $('#'+optionValue);
    selected.show('fast');
    $('.coursedate').not(selected).hide();
});
```